# How can I use the data selected in the select option, for further use? As in, using the selected option for other computations

Tags: javascript, php, html, reactjs, laravel

This is the select option what I have coded.

```
  <select class="form-control select-search" name="selectedUser" id="selectedUser" required style="width: 200px;">
    <option value="" selected> Select ID </option>
     @foreach($users as $user)
      <option value="{{ $user }}"  class="text-capitalize">{{ $user->name }}</option>
     @endforeach
  </select>
```

I'm using Laravel here, and please do explain with related ones

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly are you asking. Can you elaborate your question a bit?

Comment: Okay @zlatan , so now I will select one user-name from the drop-down. Now I want to retrieve the user details of that particular user further in the project.

Comment: What is your request method `GET` or `POST`?

Comment: @AakashTushar, POST.

Comment: And first you should echo `value="{{ $user->id }}"`

Answer (score 0):

php/laravel is used to generate a template written in html which will be send to the browser. Then you need to define a strategy on client side to manipulate your data.

## No javascript

You can have a `<form method="post" action="process.php">` tag which on submit will send to `process.php` form's data, including the selected value.

## Vanilla JS

Using pure javascript, you can access the `<select>` using `getElementById('selectedUser')` like this :

```
var e = document.getElementById("selectedUser");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

## React

You will need to create a [react component](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) to render your form, and then can use a `onChange` event to access the value and store it on a [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) component. Might be worth checking the react documentation for further exemples with [forms and the select tags](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select class="form-control select-search" name="selectedUser" id="selectedUser" required style="width: 200px;">
    <option value="" @if(null == Request::old('selectedUser')) selected @endif> Select ID </option>
     @foreach($users as $user)
      <option value="{{ $user->id }}" @if($user->id == Request::old('selectedUser')) selected @endif  class="text-capitalize">{{ $user->name }}</option>
     @endforeach
</select>
```

**Edit:**

You can also use `ternary operator` instead of `if statement` in blade like:

```
    {{ $user->id == Request::old('selectedUser') ? 'selected': '' }}
```

Comment: I think there's something wrong in the syntax you have provided.

Comment: Yes, if loop isn't actually right. I mean everything will become a statement since the if loops isn't closing

Comment: I see ' **if statement** ' is closed with `@endif`

Comment: I'm using Atom, it isn't getting where it is closed in the option properties. everything after @if is greyed out

Comment: you must install `laravel blade` syntax highlighter. btw did you try to run the application and did it give any syntax error?